# Copy file with specific name from one folder to another in python

Tags: python, shutil

I am trying to copy specific files from one folder to another but I get an error I don't understand why :

```
import os
import shutil

def setPath_getData():        
        # Set up folders for data
    newpath = r'userdata' 
    if not os.path.exists(newpath):
        os.makedirs(newpath)
        os.makedirs('userdata/sleep')
        os.makedirs(r'userdata/distance')
        os.makedirs(r'userdata/steps')
        os.makedirs(r'userdata/lightly')
        os.makedirs(r'userdata/mod')
        os.makedirs(r'userdata/sedentary')
        os.makedirs(r'userdata/very')
        os.makedirs(r'userdata/heart-rate-zone')
        os.makedirs(r'userdata/heart-rate')
        
        
            # Get data from fitbit
        filenames = os.listdir("user-site-export")
        unique_filenames = set()
        for f in filenames:
            unique_filenames.add(f.split("-")[0])
        
        source = os.listdir('user-site-export/')
        dest = '/userdata/sleep/'
        
        for file in source:
            if file.startswith('sleep'):
                shutil.copy(file, dest)
            
            #ls userdata/
    print("Data loaded successfully")

setPath_getData()
```

the error it gives is :

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sleep-2020-01-09.json'
```

So it looks like it is fetching the correct files but it does not copy them to dest. Any ideas why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must specify the source path before the file variable in the copy command:
`shutil.copy(os.path.join("user-site-export", file), dest)`